# Linked List FIFO queu correction in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

i am new to Java bro-gramming(about 4 months). I have just picked up a copy of "Data Structures & Algorithms in Java" Second Edition by Robert Lafore and i am reading chapters and attempting the problems at the back. Since i am not taking an official class, i need some form of grading to teach me how my work can be improved.. what better place than the geniuses on the stack.

I am currently on chapter 5, Linked-Lists.

***Here is problem 5.1***
Implement a priority queue based on a sorted linked list. The remove operation
on the priority queue should remove the item with the smallest key.

**Container class**

```
public class LinkLL {


public static LinkLL leftConnector; //left side of node
public static String fName; //item in actual node
public static LinkLL rightConnector; //Right side of node


public LinkLL(String key)
{
    fName = key; 
    //A new LinkLL linked list has been Instantiated, 
    //although it is empty.

    rightConnector = null;
    leftConnector = null;
}


public void showName()
{
    System.out.print(fName + " " + "There are " + SortedLL.nElems + "in the list at this moment.");

}

}
```

here we have methods such as insert, delete..etc. I feel like i did a good job on the "insert" and maybe the delete? but my "sort" and "display" are giving me a run for my money. For instance, i want to display EVERY string inputted, but the way i have it, only the first one shows.

**"Abstraction"**

```
public class SortedLL {

static LinkLL currentNode;
static LinkLL firstNode;
static final LinkLL lastNode = null;
static LinkLL prequelNode;
static LinkLL sequelNode;
static float nElems;
static LinkLL l;

public static void insert(String key)
{
    if ( nElems == 0) //could have also been if(nElems == 0)
    {   
        l = new LinkLL(key); //if nothing exists, create one
        l.rightConnector = sequelNode;//the right connector is equal to the sequelNode
        sequelNode = lastNode;  // Sequel Node is equal to lastNode which is 'null'.
        prequelNode = sequelNode;
        firstNode.leftConnector = lastNode;
    }

    else if( !(nElems == 0) )
    {
        LinkLL NewEndNode;
        NewEndNode = lastNode;
        l.rightConnector = NewEndNode;
        l.leftConnector = prequelNode.rightConnector;           

    }
    //when such occurs, nodes must be re-connected
    nElems++;
}

public void remove()
{   

    if(nElems == 0) System.out.println("There are no items to remove.");
    //if( !find(key) ) System.out.println(key +" could not be located, " + "and thus cannot be removed.");


        //while ( find(key)  ) //while the key can be found
        {
            //currentNode = key;

            prequelNode.rightConnector = sequelNode.leftConnector;


            nElems--;
        }
    //when such occurs, nodes should be reconnected

}

public boolean find(LinkLL key)
{
    if (isEmpty() == true)
    {
        System.out.println("The List is Empty");
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<nElems+1; i++) 
        {
            if (i == nElems+1) 
            //added '+1' to make sure that the item to be searched for is not at the bottom(list scanned throughly)
                System.out.println("The key " + key + "has NOT been found!");
            else 
                System.out.println("The key " + key + "has been found!");
        }

    }
    return true;
}


public void sort()
{


}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if (firstNode != null) return false;
    else return false;
}

public void displayNode()
{
    LinkLL first = null;
    LinkLL current = first ;

    while (current != null)
    {
        l.showName();
        current = current.rightConnector;

    }       
}

}
```

**Main()**

```
public class sortedLLApp {
public static void main(String []args)
{
    SortedLL s = new SortedLL();

    s.isEmpty();

    s.insert("Jack");
    s.insert("Jill");
    s.insert("John");
    s.insert("Jenn");
    s.insert("James");
    s.displayNode();



}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously `sort` does nothing because you haven't implemented it at all. But maybe you should try it some and submit it as a separate question.

---

The reason your `displayNode()` does nothing is that the whole method uses local variables. Also, for some reason you've declared most of your code as `static`, which entirely defeats the purpose of having a reusable class. Admittedly, I haven't actually run your code yet, but why don't you try this:

1. Remove all instances of the word `static` from the `SortedLL` class.
2. Change `displayNode()` to this:

Code:

```
public void displayNode()
{
    LinkLL current = firstNode;

    while (current != null)
    {
        l.showName();
        current = current.rightConnector;
    }       
}
```